# Showing a Tab without explicity clicking on tab icon

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am currently working on an application im using Sencha Touch 1. 
I have 2 items in my TabPanel. Search and Alarm.

The Search tab on clicking gives a list of 4 .
When the user clicks on the 4th item in the list he should automatically be directed to Alarm Tab without manually clicking on the tab.

Is there any function that I could use to do so .

Im a beginner at Sencha touch.Suggestions are welcome .

This is my app.js

```
ToolbarDemo=new Ext.Application({
name:'ToolbarDemo',






launch:function(){





ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport=new Ext.TabPanel({
    fullscreen:true,

    defaults:
    {
        html:'',
        styleHtmlContent:true,

    } ,

    tabBar:
    {
        dock:'bottom',
        layout:{
            pack:'center'
        }

    },

    items:[
                    /*
                    {
                    xtype:'homecard'
                    },
                    */
                    {
                    xtype:'searchcard'
                    },
                    /*
                    {
                    xtype:'actioncard'
                    },
                    */                      {
                    xtype:'settingscard'

                    },

                    {
                     xtype:'morecard'

                    },







          ] ,

       });







}
});
```

And searchcard has following code (searchcard.js)

```
          Ext.regModel('Contact',{

                      fields:['firstName','lastName']
                  });

                   //create a store
                  var liststore = new Ext.data.Store({

                   model:'Contact',
                   getGroupString:function(record){
                               return record.get('firstName')[0];

                               },

                  data:[
                                       {firstName:'Network Summary'},
                                       {firstName: 'Alarms and Alerts'},

                       ]

                  });

                detailpanel=new Ext.Panel({
                                                layout:'fit',
                                                id:'detailpanel',
                                                html:'HELLO ',
                                            });


                listpanel =new Ext.List({

                         id:'indexlist',
                         store:liststore,    //take data from store created above
                         itemTpl:'{firstName}',

                         indexBar:true ,    //property of list
                         onItemDisclosure:function(record)

                                                    {



                                                             mainpanel.setActiveItem('detailpanel');

                                                    }
                        });
                 mainpanel=new Ext.Panel({

                                                                id:'mainpanel',
                                                                layout:'card',

                                                                items:[
                                                                listpanel,detailpanel
                                                                ],

                                                            });


ToolbarDemo.views.Searchcard= Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
    title:'Search',
    iconCls:'search',
    badgeText:'1',
    layout:'fit',
    //items:[listpanel],

    initComponent: function() {
            Ext.apply(this, {
                items:[mainpanel],
            });
            ToolbarDemo.views.Searchcard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
        }

})  ;

Ext.reg('searchcard',ToolbarDemo.views.Searchcard);
```

And my alarms tab has the following code (morecard.js)

```
                              Ext.regModel('Contact',{

                                      fields:['firstName','lastName']
                                  });
                    var liststore = new Ext.data.Store({

                                      model:'Contact',
                                      getGroupString:function(record){
                                                  return record.get('firstName')[0];

                                                  },

                                     data:[
                                                          {firstName:'Critical Alarms'},
                                                          {firstName: 'Major alarms'},
                                                          {firstName: 'Minor alarms'},
                                                          {firstName: 'Alerts'},
                                          ]

                                     });

                         detailpanel=new Ext.Panel({

                                                                        id:'detailpanel',
                                                                        tpl:'HELLO ',
                                                                    });


                        listpanel_my =new Ext.List({

                                                id:'indexlist',
                                                store:liststore,    //take data from store created above
                                                itemTpl:'{firstName}',

                                                indexBar:true ,    //property of list
                                                onItemDisclosure:function(record)

                                                                           {



                                                                                  //   ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');

                                                                           }
                                               });


            ToolbarDemo.views.Morecard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
                title: "Alarms",
                iconCls: "more",
                cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
                initComponent: function() {
                    Ext.apply(this, {
                      items:[listpanel_my] ,
                    });
                    ToolbarDemo.views.Morecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            });

            Ext.reg('morecard', ToolbarDemo.views.Morecard);
```

i spefically want when i click list item named Alarms and Alerts in Search Tab (searchard.js) after that I  automatically want my Alarms tab to be active and show its items (Major Alarms, minor Alarms etc)

Comment: I have edited my question again please refer to it .

Comment: Sorry for the indentation and other unneccesary code . I had to create a dummy code as I cannot copy paste my orginal code and other files here.

Answer (score 1):

Your TabPanel has a method called `setActiveItem(item)` where `item` is a number.

Also refer to the Sencha Touch Docs [regarding this method](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-setActiveItem). `Container` is the superclass of `TabPanel`.

Comment: I specifically want to click on disclosure icon of list item on first Tab , and it should make the second tab active.
Please can you tell exactly what do i write in onItemdisclosure function of list .
Also I had tried ToolbarDemo.views.Viewport.setActiveItem('morecard') //morecard is id for second tab , it gives me error saying Cannot read property 'isComponent' of undefined

Comment: As far as I am aware, you need to pass **either an integer or a configuration object** to `setActiveItem`. The integer corresponds to the number of the item in the `items` collection of your `Panel`. A configuration object would be a new view, which will then be added to the panel.